# Core Data SIGABRT When Fetching Data?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, sigabrt

In my app I have a feature that allows the user to create their own table view of ingredients that they are allergic to. Here is my method for creating the array that populates it as well as the methods that are there to populate it:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    badIngredientsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    rightButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Add"
                                               style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:nil action:nil];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightButton;

    rightButton.target = self;
    rightButton.action = @selector(addRow);

    self.tableView.delegate = self;
    self.tableView.dataSource = self;
    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations.
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"AllergicIngredient" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    NSError *error;

    NSArray *ingredientsArray = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
    badIngredientsArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:ingredientsArray];
}

-(void)addRow
{
    UIAlertView *myAlertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Add a Bad Ingredient" message:@"Type the name of the ingredient" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:@"Cancel", nil];
    myAlertView.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput;
    [myAlertView show];
}

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];
    AllergicIngredient *allergic = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"AllergicIngredient" inManagedObjectContext:context];

    NSString *enteredString = [[alertView textFieldAtIndex:0] text];

    [allergic setValue:enteredString forKey:@"name"];

    NSError *error;

    if (![context save:&error])
    {
        NSLog(@"Couldnt find the save %@", error.localizedDescription);
    }    
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"It saved properly");
    }

    [badIngredientsArray addObject:enteredString];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

It seems as though when I remove the following code:

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"AllergicIngredient" inManagedObjectContext:context];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

NSError *error;

NSArray *ingredientsArray = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
badIngredientsArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:ingredientsArray];
```

The functionality works fine, but it loses the core data aspect where if you delete the app and relaunch it the table view is empty. So I can't seem to wrap my head around what is wrong with the above code. For all of you who want to know where the `SIGABRT` error is happening, it's at this line:

```
cell.textLabel.text = [badIngredientsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

UPDATE:

My table view methods:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
return [badIngredientsArray count];
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

   if (cell == nil)
 {
   cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
 }

cell.textLabel.text = [badIngredientsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

return cell;
}
```

Comment: Please, show us your `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` and `numberOfSectionsInTableView:`.

Comment: You are performing a Core Data fetch from the main thread. This is bad. You are also using thread confinement, which is obsolete. Use queue confinement with a private queue context, you will be much happier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[badIngredientsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]` does not return a `NSString` but a `NSManagedObject`.

In `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, try the following code in order to get your `name` attribute:

```
AllergicIngredient *object = (AllergicIngredient *)[badIngredientsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.textLabel.text = object.name;
//or
//NSManagedObject *object = (NSManagedObject *)[badIngredientsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
//cell.textLabel.text = [object objectForKey:@"name"];
```